# ArgumentException for SecondaryTile constructor

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

When I am trying to create a `SecondaryTile` in the `PinToStartAsync`, I got an `ArgumentException`. Which arguments are used incorrectly?

```
    public const string LogoPath = "ms-appx:///Assets/monotone_no_bg.png";
    public static async Task<bool> PinToStartAsync(Playlist playlist, bool isPlaylist)
    {
        string tilename = playlist.Name;
        string tileid = isPlaylist ? tilename : $"{tilename}+++{playlist.Artist}";
        string path = LogoPath;
        if (playlist.DisplayItem.Source != null && await SecondaryTileFolder.TryGetItemAsync(tilename) == null)
        {
            StorageFile thumbnail = await (await GetStorageItemThumbnailAsync(playlist.DisplayItem.Source.Path)).SaveAsync(SecondaryTileFolder, tilename);
            path = thumbnail.Path;
        }
        var tile = new SecondaryTile(tileid, tilename, isPlaylist.ToString(), new Uri(path), TileSize.Default);
        // Other code
    }

    // This function saves a StorageItemThumbnail and returns a StorageFile
    public static async Task<StorageFile> SaveAsync(this StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail, StorageFolder folder, string name)
    {
        using (var stream = thumbnail.CloneStream())
        {
            var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
            var softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
            var filename = $"{name}.png";
            var item = await folder.TryGetItemAsync(filename);
            var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            if (item == null)
            {
                using (var filestream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, filestream);
                    encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);
                    await encoder.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
            return file;
        }
    }
```

More source code is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Helpers/Helper.cs) at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on your thumbnail link.

> Images can be used from the app's package, the app's local storage, or from the web.
>   —— [tile document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/create-adaptive-tiles#images)

The file path is obtained by `thumbnail.Path`, which is similar to `C:\Windows\...`, it is not allowed.

In the **SaveAsync** method, you created `{name}.png` in `LocalFolder`. If you want to access this file, you need to use the link: `ms-appdata:///local/{name}.png`.

Best regards.

Comment: I used `SecondaryTileFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("SecondaryTiles", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);` to create the SecondaryTilesFolder and now my path is `ms-appdata:///SecondaryTiles/{name}.png` but I still got the same exception.

Comment: `ms-appdata:///local/` refers to **LocalFolder**, your **SecondaryTiles** is a subfolder of LocalFolder, so the path should be `ms-appdata:///local/SecondaryTiles/{name}.png`